# How to create user control combobox with dropdown

Tags: c#, combobox, user-controls

I am learning about creating user controls, although I've been programming c# for many years.  What I am trying to achieve is a multi-column combobox with auto-complete that 1: allows more than 1 character when searching and 2: displays all columns when auto-completing.  I have found nothing like it out there.

I am intending to implement it using a TextBox, a button for opening the dropdown, and a panel control that contains a lightweight datagrid.

I can get the TextBox & Button to display fine, and the button event fires as well. What I cannot figure out is how to create & display the panel control. I've tried adding the panel to the user control using this.Controls.Add(panel) and also tried adding it to the parent form.

Sorry if this is a simple question or I'm missing something obvious.
I have gone through the MS walkthrough and another tutorial but they don't demonstrate how to make a dropdown panel appear dynamically.

THANKS in advance for any advice or pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular button use a ToggleButton then when it's toggled use its state to display a Popup.